# Cannot Resolve Symbol SetOnEditorActionListener

Tags: java, android

Trying to hook up an event listener to an EditText field in Android studio, and im getting thrown an error. Here is my event listener:

```
TextView editText = new TextView (this);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener (new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
        {
            //Write what you want to achieve
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

and here is my xml for the EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etValue"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:password="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />
```

I've tried importing *widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener* but Android Studio is still saying that the setOnEditorActionListener symbol cannot be resolved.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having an issue with that error message about an hour ago and my issue was resolved by allowing Android Studio to automatically generate the methods defined by the interface for me. You can apparently do this yourself as well, but it was easier for me to let A.S. do it... good luck!